# How to create rows using a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset that looks like this :

```
ColA; ColB; ColC;
PAR; BKK; Y;
BKK; SYD; Y;  
NYC; LAX; Y;
LAX; SFO; Y;
```

I want to duplicate the rows where ColC==Y and if colB of a row==colA of another row, then I want to create a row with these values : colA of the first and colB of the second. In our example, it would look like this:

```
ColA; ColB; ColC;
PAR; SYD; Y; 
NYC; SFO; Y;
```

And these rows would be added to the main dataset.

I have tried using a "for" loop, and generating a temporary dataset to rbind the two, but it doesn't work.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(maindataset)){
    for (j in (i+1):nrow(maindataset)-1){
        if (maindataset$colB[i]==maindataset$colA[j] & maindataset$colC[i]==maindataset$colC[j]) {
        newDF<-data.frame(ColA=maindataset$colA[i],ColB=maindataset$colA[j],ColC=maindataset$colA[j],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    maindataset<-rbind(maindataset,newDF)
}
}
}
```

I'm not sure that a loop is the best solution. Do you have any idea of the way I could solve it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general whenever you need to equate two columns in a dataset, think of doing a join. In this case, first filter out the rows where `colB` is present in `colA`, then you can do a left join with the original dataset. That should give you the rows you require. Then you can do an `rbind` to add them to the original dataset after selecting the appropriate rows and renaming them as needed:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(colA=sample(state.abb,20,replace = T),
             colB=sample(state.abb,20,replace = T)) %>% 
  filter(colA!=colB)
df # Sample dataframe with two columns having data from same superset
#> # A tibble: 19 x 2
#>    colA  colB 
#>    <chr> <chr>
#>  1 NM    CT   
#>  2 IA    TN   
#>  3 IN    FL   
#>  4 AZ    ME   
#>  5 TN    OK   
#>  6 WY    IN   
#>  7 TX    KY   
#>  8 OR    TX   
#>  9 IN    RI   
#> 10 MO    ID   
#> 11 MT    IA   
#> 12 NE    NY   
#> 13 CA    TN   
#> 14 NE    VT   
#> 15 NV    CT   
#> 16 NH    SD   
#> 17 OH    GA   
#> 18 DE    MN   
#> 19 MT    NE

df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(colB %in% colA) %>% # filter the rows where `colB` is present in `colA`
  left_join(df, by=c('colB'='colA')) # Left join with original dataset
df1
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   colA  colB  colB.y
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 IA    TN    OK    
#> 2 WY    IN    FL    
#> 3 WY    IN    RI    
#> 4 OR    TX    KY    
#> 5 MT    IA    TN    
#> 6 CA    TN    OK    
#> 7 MT    NE    NY    
#> 8 MT    NE    VT

df1 %>% 
  select(-colB) %>% 
  rename(colB=colB.y) $ colB.y is the column you need, so rename it and drop the other one
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   colA  colB 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 IA    OK   
#> 2 WY    FL   
#> 3 WY    RI   
#> 4 OR    KY   
#> 5 MT    TN   
#> 6 CA    OK   
#> 7 MT    NY   
#> 8 MT    VT
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems you tried to obtain `newDF` but you encounter some difficulty. Here is a base R solution that may be helpful to you

```
newDF <- with(subset(df,ColC == "Y"), 
              data.frame(ColA = ColA[na.omit(p <-match(ColA,ColB))],
                         ColB = ColB[which(!is.na(p))],
                         ColC = "Y"))
```

such that

```
> newDF
  ColA ColB ColC
1  PAR  SYD    Y
2  NYC  SFO    Y
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("PAR", "BKK", "NYC", "LAX"), ColB = c("BKK", 
"SYD", "LAX", "SFO"), ColC = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```